# Assembly generation - Reference assembly targets different processor

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting following warning

```
Assembly generation -- Referenced assembly 'System.Web.dll' targets a different processor
```

What does this mean and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It probably needs you are running on a 64 bit machine and trying to use a 32 bit API or vice-versa

[See this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=510573&wa=wsignin1.0) for a possible fix.